# Best solution to test angular services making use of Parse SDK with Karma

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to automate the testing of Angular services which happen to make calls to Parse.com through Parse SDK.

The problem I have got is that the promises dont get resolved unless I explicitely trigger a digest cycle, and the way my services are done, I have to do that in my services implementations which is not sustainable.

My service code is the following :

```
factory('myService', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {

  var myService = {};

  myService.simplePromiseTest = function() {
    var p = $q.defer();
    var query = new Parse.Query("AnyObjectInParse");
    query.find().then(function(results){
      p.resolve(results);

      // *** I have to include that line for the jasmine test to run ***
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });     
    return p.promise;
  }
 }

 return myService;
```

}

And here is my jasmine test

```
async.it('should resolve the promise', function(done) {
  myService.simplePromiseTest().then(function(results) {
    // this is never called if don't trigger the digest from the service code
    done();
   });

   // This line is use less as when I get into that line, the promise is not resolved.
   // $scope.$root.$digest();
});
```

So the situation is as following :

- I have to wait for the call to parse to end before triggering a digest cycle
- I can't find any other solution than to pollute my service's code with this code
- I'd like to find a sustainable solution which doesn't require me to update my service's code to pass the test.

Thanks in advance I'm lost with that, I may be missing something obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

Call `$rootScope.$apply();` in the test itself rather than in the promise implementation. Tests with `done` are asynchronous so it's ok to resolve it afterwards. Alternatively use Angular 1.3.

In general for testing promises I'd probably recommend mocha rather than Jasmine since it supports promise tests out of the box with `return` statements.

Comment: Hi Benjamin see the commented line, when I call $rootScope.$apply() from inside the test, it is called before the promise has been resolved an thus has no effect.

Comment: What version of Angulr are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using Ionic Framework which seems to use Angular 1.2 in the version I currently have installed. Is 1.3 supposed to behave differently regarding resolving promises ?

Comment: Yes, it does. It no longer requires the `$apply`